# Allocating and freeing memory in C in a good manner

Tags: c, pointers, memory, free, calloc

This is maybe a more general question. I have a pointer in my code to store some data. The size of the pointer is determined only while the program is executed and needs to be allocated dynamically.

So I'm using

```
calloc()
```

to allocate memory and set it to zero. After the run of the program I'm using

```
free()
```

to free it.

Is this usage of memory in a good manner? Or is there something more "nice" one could do?

Comment: What you write makes perfectly sense. It's hard to tell if its "good" or not without seeing any code though. But so far it's OK, you allocate memory and once you're done with it you free it.

Comment: if you don't need to initialize data with zero better to use `malloc()`.

Comment: I think you'll have to be a bit more specific - what do you mean by "nice"? Maybe you should post your code on the [code review site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get some feedback on whether your code needs improvement.

Comment: Depending on the size of it, you could use a Variable Length Array, to prevent you from having to do manual memory management. But more information about your implementation would be needed to decide.

Comment: You need to provide a specific example. But, some general tips: always check the return values of `malloc()` etc. for allocation errors; always store the return value from `realloc()` in a temporary variable to avoid memory leaks in case of allocation error; do not double-free allocated memory.

Comment: It is always a good idea to set the pointer to NULL after a delete, that eliminates the possibility of use-after-free, which can lead to security issues. For example a Macro wrapper `#define SAFE_DEL(x) delete x; x = NULL;`

Comment: You say _"The size of the pointer is determined only while the program is executed"_ — that's an inaccurate (though comprehensible) statement.  The size of the pointer is fixed at compile time; the size of the data area that the pointer points at is determined when the program is run.

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic memory allocation, the steps you had mentioned is correct, as @Stargateur pointed use malloc(), if you don't need to initialize the memory allocated.

Also take care to free the allocated memory, on all possible exit condition of the program.